# Java Hibernate write query to sum values from list

Tags: java, spring, jpa

From one query `findAllByName(personName)` I am getting back List Objects. I want to sum their age. So I make something like this:

```
  int sum =
                listPerson
                        .stream()
                        .mapToInt(PersonEntity::getAge)
                        .sum();
```

I know that I can use for example EntityManager and Query:

```
   Query query = em.createQuery(
              "SELECT SUM(p.age) FROM PErson p");
```

But it will sum age from all entities.

How can I write a query instead of this, to sum Person age from list, based on argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function inside your repository which will return a `Long` or `int` (depends on your database size) type and is annotated with `@Query`

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(age) FROM Person", nativeQuery = true)
Long getAgeSum();
```

**EDIT**: After your edit, the current method could be modified like this for

1) **List arguments**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(p.age) FROM Person p WHERE p.id IN :idList", nativeQuery = true)
Long getAgeSum(@Param("idList") List<String> idList);
```

2) **Simple arguments**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(p.age) FROM Person p WHERE p.jobName=:jobNameParam", nativeQuery = true)
Long getAgeSum(@Param("jobNameParam") String jobNameParam);
```

Comment: I think it is better to use the ```long``` return type instead of the ```int```

Comment: Yes, it could be better depends on the database size. Thank you. (Edited)

Comment: Thank you for advice. But I would like use Long getAgeSum(String argument). Lets say String is jobName. Find all Person based on jobName and later sum their ages. Something like I used in lambda expression but in one query.

Comment: Could you help me with one more thing. How can I now convert nativeQuery in JPA to SQL query. I mean with List arguments 1). It should do the same but use SQL instead, and later I just want to try with EntityManager.

Comment: `nativeQuery = true` means that the query from the `@Query` annotation is SQL.

Comment: Ahh, you are right. So just create EntityManager and use the same query :). Thanks